# Display points labels starting at certain zoom level

Tags: geoserver, sld

I use WMS to display my points on the map. I would like to display points labels(name_ID) starting at certain zoom level. From What I have read I understand I can do it with GeoServer rules, but I need a clear example to clarify this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to define 2 different [sld:Rules](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.3.0/user/styling/sld-reference/rules.html) using MaxScaleDenominator. In the first one, add the style to render the label (the TextSymbolizer in my example), and specify the desired zoom level with the right MaxScaleDenominator.
In the second rule, define a different style without the label.
Basically, a rule contains a style, an only the style whith the satisfied rule is applied to the features.

This is one of my sld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"              xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>locations_table</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>locations_table</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>A boring default style</sld:Title>
      <sld:Abstract>A sample style that just prints out a green line</sld:Abstract>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>68000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>
                <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                  </sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
          <sld:TextSymbolizer>            
            <sld:Label>            
              <ogc:PropertyName>name1</ogc:PropertyName> <![CDATA[
              ]]><ogc:PropertyName>name2</ogc:PropertyName>
            </sld:Label>
            <sld:Font>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">11</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Font>
        <sld:LabelPlacement>              
          <sld:PointPlacement>
            <sld:AnchorPoint>
              <sld:AnchorPointX>
                <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
              </sld:AnchorPointX>
              <sld:AnchorPointY>
                <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
              </sld:AnchorPointY>
            </sld:AnchorPoint>
            <sld:Displacement>
              <sld:DisplacementX>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </sld:DisplacementX>
              <sld:DisplacementY>
                <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
              </sld:DisplacementY>
            </sld:Displacement>
            <sld:Rotation>
              <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
            </sld:Rotation>
          </sld:PointPlacement>
        </sld:LabelPlacement>            
        <sld:Fill>
          <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Fill>
        <sld:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">true</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:TextSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:MinScaleDenominator>68000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
      <sld:PointSymbolizer>
        <sld:Graphic>
          <sld:Mark>
            <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:Mark>
          <sld:Size>
            <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
          </sld:Size>
        </sld:Graphic>
      </sld:PointSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
```

Comment: while this is technically a correct answer it doesn't really help the questioner figure out what to do

Comment: @iant I improved the answer, but actually there is not so much to explain...also the questioner was asking for an example :)

Comment: Doesn't this apply to the points as well as their labels? I think the question was about turning the labels on and off at different scales, not the points too.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the following sentences:

```
 <sld:MinScaleDenominator>68000.0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
 <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>68000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
```

They set the limits to apply a rule.

**Examples**: [in the official GeoServer docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/index.html) and [this other doc](https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+SLD+-+Maps+with+Curved+Labels)